# What is different call a function from another function for a loop

Tags: function, python-3.x, call

When I wrote a simple program in python, It creates a question for me! I have a `loop` and want to run a function's work as loop count. But I get loop number from the user. I want to know which of the following approach is better and why?

**First Method:**

```
def game(redCard, blackCard):
    global totalRed, totalBlack
    redWin = False
    if redCard == king and blackCard == king:
        redWin = True
    elif redCard != king and blackCard != king and redCard != blackCard:
        redWin = True

    if(redWin):
        totalRed += 1
    else:
        totalBlack += 1



def main():
    #start point of program
    n = int(input("Please enter 'Rounds' numbers:"))
    for i in range(n):
        # randint(a,b): Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b
        redCard = random.randint(0, 3)
        blackCard = random.randint(0, 3)
        game(redCard, blackCard)


main()
```

**Second Method:**

```
def game(count):

    global totalRed, totalBlack

    for i in range(count):
         # randint(a,b): Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b
         redCard = random.randint(0, 3)
         blackCard = random.randint(0, 3)

         redWin = False

         if redCard == king and blackCard == king:
             redWin = True
         elif redCard != king and blackCard != king and redCard != blackCard:
            redWin = True

        if(redWin):
            totalRed += 1
        else:
            totalBlack += 1



def main():
    #start point of program
    n = int(input("Please enter 'Rounds' numbers:"))
    game(n)
```